# Finding all triplets of primes $(p,q,r)$ such that $pq=r+1$ and $2(p^2+q^2)=r^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, systems-of-equations

Find the number of triplets $(p,q,r)$ such that $p,q,r$ are prime and they satisfy

$$pq=r+1$$ &
$$2(p^2+q^2)=r^2+1$$

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h573988_diophantine_equation_with_primes_and_squares

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

$$pq=r+1\tag 1$$
$$2(p^2+q^2)=r^2+1\tag2$$
The LHS of $(2)$ is even, so $r$ has to be odd. So, the RHS of $(1)$ is even.

It follows from this that we have either $p=2$ or $q=2$.

Comment: As the system is symmetric in $p$ and $q$…

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $r$ must be odd so $r+1$ is even. Hence by symmetry we can do $p=2$ so the system $2q=r+1$ and $2(4+q^2)=r^2+1$ determines uniquely the solutions $(q,r)=(3,5)$

Comment: @shrey The above already proves that no other solutions exist.  What is your question exactly?  You haven't provided any context.

Comment: @Erick Wong: I have received today by mail your comment to shrey (I also have many distractions.....).Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-$r$ must be odd form the second equation.Try to prove why.The proof follows.

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation, $r+1=pq\ge 4$,  hence $r\ge 3$, so $r+1$ is even. This implies $p$ or $q$ is an even prime.  As the system of equations is symmetric in $p$ and $q$, we may suppose $p=2$. The system becomes
$$\begin{cases}r=2q-1\\8+2q^2=4q^2-4q+2\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}r=2q-1\\q^2-2q-3=0\end{cases}$$
The second equation has $-1$ and $3$ as roots. Hence the solution is
$$(p,q,r)=(2,3,5)\enspace\text{or}\enspace (3,2,5).$$